# Proper Use of Android BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray

Tags: android, bitmap

I have searched for some time now and I cannot find an example implementation for android's BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()

I am looking to understand how function works as I am planning to use it for a project I am working on, but I haven't been able to get a simple example working. Here is the code I have:

```
public Bitmap createRandomBitmap() {
    int h = 300;
int w = 300;

buf = new byte[h * w * 4];

for (int i = 0; i < h * w * 4;i++) {
    buf[i] = 127;
}

bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buf, 0, h * w);
return bmp;
}
```

This always returns null, which according to the documentation means the bitmap failed to load. But I can't figure out why. This should be using the default ARGB_8888 format, where each pixel has 4 bytes. I thought I had taken care of that above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a raw `Bitmap` the way you are, `BitmapFactory` is not the answer. Use `setPixel()` on `Bitmap`, or some flavor of the `createBitmap()` factory method on `Bitmap`, or create a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas` and draw using `Canvas` operations.

`BitmapFactory` is for decoding bitmaps in recognized formats, such as PNG and JPEG.